# What are some popular DSLs?

Tags: dsl

I'm looking for popular domain specific languages. I believe CSS is one and XML/HTML could possibly fall into one? (Although that seems more data than language). The only other one i can come up with is the starcraft map editor...

What are some popular domain specific languages?

Comment: SQL?  INI files?  Markdown?  Half of Ruby?

Comment: `<whatever>something</whatever>`: does it exist something less specific than XML?

Comment: Regular expression is one of best examples of DSL

Answer (score 4):

The trick about domain-specific languages is that you define your own language for your specific problem domain. Or, as stated by Kerzhner (2009) *"A DSL is a language that is tailored to describe a particular problem domain."* [1]

From that perspective, HTML is a bad example because only few people defined HTML for there problem domain but much more people use it as a standard language for designing websites.

Hence, the question could be also: ***Are there popular languages to define DSLs?*** These are languages to define other languages, i.e. metalanguages. I would consider the languages around the Eclipse-Modeling Framework (EMF), OMG's Meta-Object-Facility as the two most common ones. However, GrGen's metamodeling capabilities are also quite impressing and probably easier to learn.

Btw: At Soley, we are building software for developing domain-specific languages. [Soley Studio](https://www.soley.io/en/pr-soley-studio/) is an integrated development environment for defining graph-based, domain-specific languages that can be used for modeling as well as data analytics.

---

[1]: Kerzhner, A. A., & Paredis, C. J. J. (2009). Using Domain Specific Languages to Capture Design Synthesis Knowledge for Model-Based Systems Engineering. ASME 2009 International Design Engineering Technical Conferences & Computers and Information in Engineering Conference, IDETC/CIE 2009. San Diego, USA.

Answer (score 3):

[SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/), or specifically the SuperCollider client (sclang), is considered a DSL used for real-time audio synthesis and algorithmic composition. Additionally, there are other client-side implementations, including [ScalaCollider](https://github.com/Sciss/ScalaCollider) and [Overtone](http://overtone.github.com/), which use Scala and Clojure (respectively) to talk to the SuperCollider server.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language):

> Examples of domain-specific languages include
>
> - HTML,
> - Logo for children,
> - Verilog and VHDL hardware description languages,
> - Mata for matrix programming,
> - Mathematica and Maxima for symbolic mathematics,
> - spreadsheet formulas and macros,
> - SQL for relational database queries,
> - YACC grammars for creating parsers,
> - regular expressions for specifying lexers,
> - the Generic Eclipse Modeling System for creating diagramming languages,
> - Csound for sound and music synthesis,
> - and the input languages of GraphViz and GrGen, software packages used for graph layout and graph rewriting.